# List index out of range error when count Action in RDD is used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I am new to Pyspark and I tried to find the number of Specific String('Private Room') from CSV using RDD count Action but I get a  list index out of range error.

When I use a take(20) action, I am able to see the output.

Below is the code I used. what might be reason for the error?

```
    # to Read a CSV File
    rdd1= sc.textFile("/content/M_NYC.csv")

    #Function to get the specific index 
    def pas(as1):
      f=as1.split(',')
      return([f[0],f[8]])

    #calling the function pas
    ma = rdd1.map(pas) 
    #Filtering only the records having 'Private room'
    a = ma.filter(lambda x : (x[1] == 'Private room'))
    a.count()
```

Below is the error message.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f11c6a8bc4f8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 a.count()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5) (9637d97106be executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 830, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 820, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 828, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2297, in <lambda>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2297, in <genexpr>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 81, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-6-4ca20dd5814f>", line 3, in pas
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:767)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:749)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 830, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 820, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 828, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2297, in <lambda>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2297, in <genexpr>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 81, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-6-4ca20dd5814f>", line 3, in pas
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:767)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:749)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more

I tried Count Action and I got the above error when I tried with take() action I am unable to find the output and I get an runtime error. how can I get the number of private room using RDD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using:

```py
   #Function to get the specific index 
    def test_pas(as1):
      f=as1.split(',')
      return(len(f))

    #calling the function test_pas
    ma = rdd1.map(test_pas)
```

And checking what the `min` value for that column is.

My guess is `f[8]` does not exist for one line, which is killing your whole process.

Comment: Yes, there was one particular record which does not have f[8]. Thank you